# Cant find docker container url

Tags: docker

I have a problem obtaining a URL.

I am new to docker and I have 1 docker host with 3 containers.
I know the host IP (157.38.143.12) and I have 3 docker containers set up, each with its own API. How would I get the URL/IP for this container so I can make calls to it externally? When I run "docker inspect `90de0b51890`" I get IP addresses but I can't hit any of them in postman, all the IP addresses I get start with

`172.17.0.....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are running on some cloud or machine with public access.

The IPs that you see from `docker inspect container_id` these are private and not accessible from the outside.

All you need to publish port from the container and the IP should be use of the host system.

```
docker run -dit -p 80:80 nginx
```

this container will be accessible using HOST IP and the publish port that is `80`.
So for the rest of your three container

```
docker run -dit  -p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT my_container
```

and URL/IP will

```
HOST_IP:PUBLISH_PORT
#in your case
157.38.143.12:PUBLISH_PORT
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much but im getting this error "Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use."

Comment: this is because port `80` is already occupied, try to kill the process that occupied the port or run container on other port like `docker run -dit -p 8080:80 nginx`